# Using Git with an Open Source Project

Tags: git, github

I have to work on a project to develop a module for the platform MagicMirror² (https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror), and as I am a beginner with Git I don't know how to do to simply import the files and work with them to test my module.

What I did was to import a repository, but now I see that the project is getting modified regularly, so I suppose this is for people who want to improve it and are pushing their changes.

So what should I do if I simply want to develop my module, while if possible benefiting from the updates of the main project ? Should I import the repository, commit and push my changes of my module, without having the risk to mess up the original project or should I simply make a new repository ?

I also saw these branches, forks "things", I understand the concepts, but I don't know how should I use them.

Thank you

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start, you need to have `Git` installed. After that, find the repository URL, in your case it's:

```
https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror.git
```

and do

```
git clone https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror.git
```

After that, you can simply checkout (create) a new branch:

```
git checkout -b [branchname]
```

and work/commit/push **on** this branch. You will not affect content that is in other branches and while pushing, you will be asked to merge/rebase etc.

Also, keep in mind that `git pull`-ing new changes might cause damage, read [this article](https://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) to have a deeper understanding.

Comment: Thank you very much ! If I'm correct, making a new branch will simply allow me to get the updates while making my own module on it ?

Comment: Yes, and you are not affecting other's work. If you think this answer helped you, consider *accepting* it so other people can find it in future.